# PiTFT Touchscreen calibration is ignored by Pi Zero W

Tags: touchscreen, xorg, pitft, pi-zero-w

I'm using an Adafruit 2.4" Resistive PiTFT on my shiny new Raspberry Pi Zero W and I've finally managed to get the display configured but the touchscreen is proving a problem...  (Please note that instead of setting X11's framebuffer to `/dev/fb1` to get X11 to show up on the touchscreen, resulting in a tiny desktop, I'm using `fbcp` from boot to copy the entire display there so I get all fullscreen programs to work, etc.).

When I use `ts_calibrate` and `ts_test`, the touchscreen calibrates and works fine, but when I use `xinput_calibrator` for trying to make the touchscreen work with X11, it makes no difference.  I've tried copying the output into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf` (as is required) and then rebooting, but that doesn't make any difference either!  Not only that, I can change the `SwapXY` value and the `InvertX` and `InvertY` values between 0 and 1 all I want and it doesn't change the mapping of the touchscreen!  All the settings are simply being ignored by the OS and I have no idea why.

Comment: I have this same problem. Going crazy trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with a raspberry pi 3 and fixed it by interchanging the  cal values like this in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf:

"calibration" "3800 120 200 3900" for /boot/config.txt rotate=270
to
"calibration" "120 3800 3900 200" for /boot/config.txt rotate=90

Use your values for the calibration.

However, I upgraded to the new Pixel OS and now nothing seems to work again to fix the pitft touch screen calibration.